# Rewriting a subdomain page on one WordPress installation to a parent domain on another

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, subdomains

How can I use `.htaccess` to rewrite a a page on a subdomain to a page on the parent? (E.g. people visiting mysite.com/landingpage will see the content from dev.mysite.com/landingpage)?

Ive been working to redesign a WordPress site, using a dev.mysite.com subdomain. The site isn't ready to replace the live WP site yet (mysite.com) but I need to map one of the pages to the old domain and make it public. Since all the work (template,database,etc)  is on the subdomain, I can't just import the page to the old domain, so I seemingly need to use `mod_rewrite`, which is way beyond my skill level.
Also, since its two different WP Installations (not multisite), would I use the domain `.htaccess` file or the subdomain `.htaccess` file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the main domain `.htaccess` file when people go onto the page you want to display on the sub domain it will change the url link to `dev.mysite.com` I am not sure if that is the best approach but if you want to do it that way you would have to use the main domains `.htaccess` to redirect to the subdomain.

Another option could be export the page's data with a WordPress exporting plugin. A search on the website led me to this one which may be of some use. https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-exporter/

Comment: As I tried to explain, because its two separate WordPress installations (different versions, themes, functions.php, plugins, and more) I can't just export the page to the parent domain). Also, Im not trying to redirect to a different page, but rewrite the url. And the goal is to make dev.mysite.com/page appear when someone visits mysite.com/page (keeping the url that the visitor used).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be speaking of URL masking.  Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928498/htaccess-url-masking-instead-of-redirecting) and [here](https://www.siteground.com/kb/url_masking_with_htaccess/) for examples.

A visitor to example.com/mypage can be shown example.net/mypage while seeing example.com/mypage in the address bar.  Not sure how you'd handle the links from example.net/mypage back to the main site instead of the development site, but that wasn't part of the question.